# SQL sub-queries not returning expected result

Tags: sql, subquery

```
Select name 
from instructor 
where dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.' and ID in
    (select ID
     from course 
     where title != 'Intro. to Computer Science')
```

With this input I want the output to be the instructors who never taught "Intro. to Computer Science but the output is all instructors from CS rather than just the 1 Professor Brant who has not taught Intro to Computer Science. What am I doing wrong?

[image: instructor]

[image: course]

[image: teaches]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you

```
select i.name 
from instructor as i, teaches as t
where i.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.' and i.ID=t.ID
and not exists (
  select 1 
  from course 
  where t.ID = course.course_id and title = 'Intro. to Computer Science'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
select i.name 
from instructor i
where i.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.' 
and not exists (
  select 1 
  from teaches t inner join course c
  on c.course_id = t.course_id 
  where t.id = i.id and c.title = 'Intro. to Computer Science'
)
```

or group by instructor and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select i.name 
from instructor i
inner join teaches t on t.id = i.id
inner join course c on c.course_id = t.course_id 
where i.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'
group by i.id, i.name
having count(case when c.title = 'Intro. to Computer Science' then 1 end) = 0
```